# Apple reject my app by App Tracking Transparency, but in my app I do not use App Tracking Transparency. I have removed Firebase/Analytics from project

Tags: ios

Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

We're looking forward to completing the review of your app, but we need more information to continue. Specifically, we noticed that your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we haven't been able to locate the App Tracking Transparency permission request.

Next Steps

Please indicate where in your app we can find the AppTrackingTransparency permission request. The request should appear before any data is collected that could be used to track the user.

Apps that track user's activity must implement App Tracking Transparency and request permission before collecting data used to track.

I my project we not using App Tracking Transparency, I have removed from project Firebse/Anatytics , but still reject from Apple

Answer (score -1):

Remove location permission description in info.plist file and clean build folder.
If you are still getting same issue from apple, then restart your Xcode again.
Thanks